# Facebook integration in php mvc not working

Tags: php

Please suggest me the below `pagebuilder` connection is not working in my file,please once chek my code

This code in pagebuilder.class.php

```
     else if(isset($pAction) && $pAction=='sociallogin')
        {
            if(isset($pAction1) && $pAction1=="facebook"){
                $this->objSocialLogin->modFacebook();
            }
            else if(isset($pAction1) && $pAction1=="google"){
                $this->objSocialLogin->modGoogle();
            }
        }
```

This code in login.class.php

```
        if(empty($user)){
          //login url   
          $loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                        'scope'=> 'email',
                        'redirect_uri'=> $config['LIVE_URL'].'sociallogin/facebook',
                        'display'=>'popup'
                        ));
         header('Location: '.$loginurl);
        }
```